# CocoaPods project structure for unit testing with private components

Tags: ios, cocoapods, project-structure

I am using CocoaPods for a project with the following structure:

```
Example/
Example/PublicUmbrellaHeader.h
Example/PrivateHeaderForComponent1.h
Example/PrivateHeaderForComponent2.h
Example.podspec
Tests/
Tests/Podfile
Tests/Tests/UnitTestForPrivateComponent1.m
Tests/Tests/UnitTestForPrivateComponent2.m
```

#### Tests/Podfile

```
pod 'Example', :path => '../'
```

This is not unusual. For example, AFNetworking follows a similar structure. What *is* different is the need to expose a certain set of headers only to the unit tests.

However, I could not figure out a straightforward way to do this accomplish this. The
following method works, but it is not clean in the sense that it requires surgery on 
the public `Podspec`.

#### Example.podspec

```
s.public_header_files = 'Example/PublicUmbrellaHeader.h'
s.default_subspec = 'Public'
s.subspec 'Public'
s.subspec 'Tests' do |ss|
   ss.public_header_files = 'Example/*.h'
end
```

#### Tests/Podfile

```
pod 'Example', :path => '../'
pod 'Example/Tests', :path => '../'
```

Is there a simpler way? If not, is it because there is something wrong with what I am trying to accomplish, or simply because CocoaPods does not cater to this use case yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly modify the test target in your Example project to include the private headers in the Header Search Paths. Just go into your Unit Test target, and under **Search Paths** -> **Header Search Paths**, add:

```
$(inherited) "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Private/Example"
```

In your unit test files, you can include the headers like so:

```
#import "PrivateHeaderForComponent1.h"
#import "PrivateHeaderForComponent2.h"
```

rather than the typical `#import <Example/PrivateHeaderForComponent1.h>`

The downside is you're making assumptions about how CocoaPods lays out the files in the Pods directory, but I would rather do that than change my public podspec file.