# Can a framework cocoapod have an optional public header?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, cocoapods

So I think I have this kinda clear, based on [this blog post](http://blog.cocoapods.org/Pod-Authors-Guide-to-CocoaPods-Frameworks/) and my experiments:

- what's included by `@import MyPod;` is the auto-generated `MyPod-umbrella.h` header, which imports all the public headers according to the Podspec
- the auto-generated module map also permits explicit import of those and only those same public headers
- what's included by `#import <MyPod/MyPod.h>` header is a `MyPod.h` header that I still need to make, but it can import anything I choose that's in the module map

What I was hoping to achieve, however, was that the header for either `@import` or `#import` to include most but **not all** of my pod's public headers. I'd like one of my public headers contain optional declarations that are normally omitted, to only be included manually from the few `.m` files that need it. But it seems to not be possible when code uses `@import` since the includes in that umbrella header always matches **all** the public headers.

Specifying a custom module map is possible and would work, but doing that seems to precludes the benefits of auto-generated map & umbrella header.

Would it be kosher to do some macro & `#ifdef` tricks to skip the contents of my "optional" header when included by the `@import` but then use the contents if that header is pulled in again with an `#include`? This sounds ugly, but is it my only option?

Answer (score 0):

I found problems with all the `#ifdef` tricks I attempted when using framework cocoapods, though I'm sure they'd work when not. But I don't really want to be biased against frameworks and would like a solution for both.

So to take another approach, I found its not hard for a project to access a pod's private headers! See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29851173/592739) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28756476/592739) (that last tip is for Swift, but I'm sure the right `@import` will work in Objective-C too).

So in my cocoapod I'm going to make the optional header private, and then rely on my users to use those methods to access it if desired.